# How to create object of another class from a method

Tags: java

I have some problems with implementing some code. I have a method called *addBid* in Class *Auction* . At the same time there is a public constructor of Class Person. My aim is to create object of *Person* class within

```
public void addBid(String ItemName, String nameOfBidder, long price)
```

with help of public constructor:

```
public Person(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
```

This object of Person class should be named exactly as `String nameOfBider` and have `String name = String nameOfBidder`
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Person person = new Person(nameOfBidder);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.....

```
    private Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<>();

   public void addBid(String ItemName, String nameOfBidder, long price){
        Person person = new Person(nameOfBidder);
        personSet.add(person);
        // do whatever you want inside this method
        // in the whole class you can access the personSet as you want.
     }
```

.....

Comment: My problem is that I want create a new object of Person class each time I call addBid method. Furthermore my problem is that here , you have already called object of Person class as person. But it should flexible. For example it sholud be somehing this
Person Max=new Person("Max")

Comment: @Herr Sgory Hmm.. You know what, explain me what you want to do because i don't understand your concerns. Because the code works as you wanted, that we create a new object of Person each time we call addBid. What you want to do after you created these Person instances ?

Comment: But what if I need 2 objects of Person Class not only person but also person1 for example.

Comment: I think you are missing  Java basics. You have to explan your problem more clearly so i can write a code snippet for your needs or learn a little bit about Java object creation and references e.g a link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addBid(String ItemName, String nameOfBidder, long price){
Person person= new Person(nameOfBidder);
}
```

Although you might want to return that person from the method, so that you can do something with it:

```
public Person addBid(String ItemName, String nameOfBidder, long price){
return new Person(nameOfBidder);
}
```